# ModuleNotFoundError: Python cannot identify import statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I have tried similar questions related to this topics but none of them worked for me. I have a simple Python project structure as below:

```py
Project
|
---> src
|    |
|    ---> __init__.py  # empty file
|    ---> main.py
|
---> test
     |
     ---> test.py
```

Inside `test.py`, **I want to import everything from `main.py`**.
I've done following methods, none of them worked.

```py
from main import *
from .main import *
from src.main import *
from .src.main import *
from ..src.main import *
from src import *
from .src import *
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you calling test.py and what error do you get?

Comment: `from src.main import *` should work, I tested it on my system, it is working

Comment: @JanWilamowski `py test/test.py`. Errors are like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'`

Comment: @Don'tAccept It gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` why is that? are you putting any code inside `__init__.py`?

Comment: if this is for unit tests, have a look at the `unittest`'s module [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery). Then you should be able to do `from src import main` in your test.py.

Comment: `src` directory is up one level from `test` directory, so you want to use `from ..src`

Answer (score 0):

A common problem of mine. Try writing a setup.py file and installing your package by running `python setup.py` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Since `src` directory is "above" the `test` directory one-level, you can use `..` to specify up one-level to `src` then import the `main` sub-module as:

```
from ..src import main
```

Per [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id9) Rationale for Relative Imports / `from ...foo import bar`